# Group By in LINQ to Entities while JOIN

Tags: linq-to-entities

Following is the structure of my tables.

City: CityId, Name

Person: PersonId, CityId, Name, DateOfBirth

I am using Linq to Entities in my .NET application. I want to populate result of a desired query into an object PersonInfo (which will contain City and Person objects). 
The query should return only one entry for each City, having lowest of DateOfBirth.

How can I achieve this? any sample would be more helpful. I am able to write an L2E query using join that populates all cities and persons in the resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two tables are in variables called "cities" and "people":

```
from city in cities

join person in people
on city.CityId equals person.CityId

group person

by city

into group1

select new PersonInfo
{
    City = group1.Key,
    Person = group1.OrderBy(person => person.DateOfBirth).First()
}
```